# Крестики-нолики: функция проверки выигрыша

Tags: python

```py
# по диагонали
def win_check(board, mark):
    (Board[1] == Board[5] == Board[9] == mark) or 
    (Board[7] == Board[5] == Board[3] == mark)
```

В списке первый элемент - буква, `mark` - это или крестик или нолик, проверка по строкам и столбцам такая же. Провожу проверку и функция ничего не возвращает.
Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: *>функция ничего не возвращает* - А где Вы написали, чтобы она что-то возвращала?

Comment: и заодно где вы проводите проверку?

Comment: Проверку не стал добавлять сюда, пишу return перед сравнением он возвращает но только для диагонали а для остальных строк столбцов уже проверки нет

Answer (score 1):

> Проверку не стал добавлять сюда, пишу return перед сравнением он
> возвращает но только для диагонали а для остальных строк столбцов уже
> проверки нет – Nick Baikov 10 минут назад

потому что надо сделать сначала все проверки, а потом уже что-то возвращать
например:

```
res1 = (Board[1] == Board[5] == Board[9] == mark) or (Board[7] == Board[5] == Board[3] == mark)
res2 = по вертикали
res3 = по горизонтали

return any((res1, res2, res3))
```

или вообще все всунуть под один `if`

```
return (Board[1] == Board[5] == Board[9] == mark) or (Board[7] == Board[5] == Board[3] == mark) or (по вертикали) or (по горизонтали)
```

P.S.

а вообще если крестики-нолики на неограниченном поле и с заданным кол-вом заполнений (например последовательность из 5 крестиков), то проверку на выигрыш вообще надо делать совершенно по другому

1. отдельно проверить каждую клетку
2. в каждой клетке проверить диагонали, строки, столбцы на заданную длину в обе стороны (через циклы)

Comment: Спасибо , одной длинной строкой с return , получилось

Comment: аккуратнее только с одной строкой- потом в своем же будет тяжело разбираться :)